# MATLAB: Get mean of first n values sorted by first column

Tags: matlab, mean

I have a cell array of 21128x9 cells sorted by column 1 e.g.(massively simplified):

```
    A=[1 3; 1 5; 1 3; 2 1; 2 2; 2 3; 3 5; 3 5]

    A =

         1     3
         1     5
         1     3
         2     1
         2     2
         2     3
         3     5
         3     5
```

where some values in column 1 are repeated more than others.

what I want to do is get the mean of the second column for each value of the first column, but only for the first two values.

i.e.

```
    ans= 1 4
         2 1.5
         3 5
```

I'm attempting to use this basic function

```
    means = accumarray(A(:,1) ,A(:,2),[],@mean);
```

but i'm not sure how to get it to only apply to the first two values of each group. I assume I'll need a *for* loop, something along the lines of:

```
    for ;
        means = accumarray(A(:,1) ,A(:,2),[],@mean);
    end
```

What I don't know what what the *for* needs to be.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`accumarray` passes a vector into the anonymous function, so you can just do, e.g.:

```
A = [1 3; 1 5; 1 3; 2 1; 2 2; 2 3; 3 5; 3 5];
maxAvgs = 3;
accumarray(A(:, 1), A(:, 2), [], @(x)mean(x(1:min(length(x), maxAvgs))))

ans =

3.6667
2.0000
5.0000

maxAvgs = 2;
accumarray(A(:, 1), A(:, 2), [], @(x)mean(x(1:min(length(x), maxAvgs))))

ans =

4.0000
1.5000
5.0000
```

Whenever you're unsure in such situations involving anonymous functions, you can write your anonymous function as `@(varargin)disp(varargin)`; this will display the input arguments. In this case this doesn't work because `accumarray` **requires** that the function you pass it returns an argument. However, you can still set this as the anonymous function and run your code from a script; set a breakpoint on the line in the editor window, making sure to select 'Anonymous function' for the position of the breakpoint.

**Edit:**

> In my actual data, some have 60 values, some have 120, some have 180.
>   As an addition, is it possible to then run the mean function on the
>   next lot of values (i.e. value 61-120, then 121-180)?

To do what you you ask in the comment I suggest creating a function `splitMean` and passing this to `accumarray`:

```
function y = splitMean(x, n)
% If length of x doesn't divide by n, the extra elements will be averaged
% separately
extra = mod(length(x), n);
M = length(x)-extra;

meanData = reshape(x(1:M), M / n, n);

extraMean = [];
if extra > 0, extraMean = mean(x(M+1:end)); end
if ~isempty(meanData)
    y = {[mean(meanData).'; extraMean]};
else
    y = {extraMean};
end
```

Then,

```
maxAvgs = 2;
cell2mat(accumarray(A(:, 1), A(:, 2), [], @(x)splitMean(x, maxAvgs)))

ans =

4.0000
3.0000
1.5000
3.0000
5.0000

%%% Without the cell2mat:

ans =

[2x1 double]
[2x1 double]
[         5]
```

This way, you get all the sets of means each group can provide all at once. Note the `cell2mat`. If you want them split up by group index, then remove this and you will get a cell array.

Comment: Ah! You, Sir, are a scholar and a gentleman! It seems so simple, but I guess I haven't quite got to grips with MATLAB syntax quite yet.

Comment: In my actual data, some have 60 values, some have 120, some have 180. As an addition, is it possible to then run the mean function on the next lot of values (i.e. value 61-120, then 121-180)?